# How to Execute Micro Focus Unified Functional Testing on a Jenkins Windows Slave Node Without RDP

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hp-uft

I was Facing issue in Executing UFT Testing cases on a Remote Windows Slave Machine. Without RDP into that Machine Manual build was not Starting.

is there any Solution to Run/Execute UFT test cases without RDP in to Slave Machine or if the machine got Disconnected

We are using Jenkins as a build tool to Execute UFT test-cases.
Micro Focus Unified Functional Testing Plugin we are using in Jenkins.
on Windows Slave Machine UFT software has installed to Execute Test-cases

Thanks in Advance

Sidhartha

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in tools > Options, then on Run Sessions:

[image: Run sessions]

It can also be set with code if you need configure the remote machines:

```
Dim App 'As Application
Set App = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")
App.Launch
App.Visible = True

App.Options.Run.EnableRdp = True
App.Options.Run.RdpUserName = "HelloWorld"
App.Options.Run.RdpPasswordEncrypted = "Use the password encypter tool"
```

Be sure you're running UFT elevated when try to set this.